# JOOQ maven codegen and use of different database for buildtime and runtime

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

suppose I have following usecase:

- I want my application to run against PostgreSQL
- I have configured `jooq-codegen-maven` plugin to use H2

  - It is bacause I dont want to my builds be dependent against always running postgres

Questions:

1. Is generated code against H2 compatible with usage with postgres?
2. Does this usecase makes sense?
3. If not, how to solve it correctly (beeing less dependent to running DB instance)?

   - Can I use (somehow) testcontainers with generation process (or some similar concept)

Thank you

Ivos

Answer (score 1):

> Is generated code against H2 compatible with usage with postgres?

Yes, as long as you don't use any vendor specific features

> Does this usecase makes sense?

Sure, but I'd try other things first, including running a PostgreSQL instance in [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/). jOOQ might support that out of the box in the future: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6551. In the meantime, here's an example showing how to set it up manually, it's not too hard: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/main/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-testcontainers-example

Also, rather than rolling your own PostgreSQL/H2 setup, you could just use the [`DDLDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/codegen-ddl/), which translates PostgreSQL DDL to H2 as of jOOQ 3.13, and in the future, will simply interpret the DDL, to support more vendor specific stuff.

Comment: thank you for answer. I suppose that DDL parsing might have some glitches compared to generation (parsers fun, ambiguous dialect grammar, etc.) from running instance of database, right? And this will be solved by testcontainers support.

Comment: @bedla.czech: Well, everything is a tradeoff. You want most features? Use native PostgreSQL at the price of slightly slower code generation speed. You want more code generation speed? Use the `DDLDatabase` at the price of a significant reduction of usable PostgreSQL specific features.